# Using sort function to sort vector of tuples in a chained manner

Tags: c++, sorting

So I tried sorting my list of tuples in a manner that next value's first element equals the second element of the present tuple.(first tuple being the one with smallest first element)

(x can be anything)

**unsorted**

3 5 x

4 6 x

1 3 x

2 4 x

5 2 x

**sorted**

1 3 x

3 5 x

5 2 x

2 4 x

4 6 x

I used  the following function as my third argument in the custom sort function

```
bool myCompare(tuple<int,int,int>a,tuple<int,int,int>b){
   if(get<1>(a) == get<2>(b)){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

But my output was unchanged. Please help me fix the function or suggest me another way.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the vector can't be sorted in this manner, e.g. `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`?

Comment: Your comparison function does not follow a `strict-weak-order`, thus the behavior is undefined.  You return `true` for identical items, which automatically is a violation of `strict-weak-order`.

Comment: There would not be such an instance in my case. You can assume that  a chain can be always be formed.

Comment: And what if multiple sorts are valid? e.g., `{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}` could be sorted with any of the members first.

Comment: I think you need to do depth first search with backtracking if you hit a dead end. I don't have the benefit of a CS degree however, so there may be a more elegant way.

Comment: How do you select the first element?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you modify the function?

Comment: The `sort` function wants to know, given two elements, which one should come before the other.  You returned `true` if both items are equal.  However if the compiler were to switch `a` and `b`, you still return `true`.  You can't have `a < b` and `b < a` at the same time.

Comment: There are  dsitinct tuples forming the first and last of the chain and the first one is the the tuple with smallest first element

Comment: Transitive.  `{1 3 x} < {3 5 x} < {5 2 x}` is all good, however `{1 3 x} is not less than {5 2 x}` and that's bad.

Comment: @SilentGuaridan -- Let's make it simple -- the compiler is going to hand you two items, and you are to unambiguously say which item comes before the other.  No more, no less.  You have no idea which two items the compiler will pick out and have you test, and you have no idea about any other items except the two items you are being tested on -- that's how you should approach this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah thanks. I can't put the idea into code, I am trying. Just wanted to know if it's possible through this way of custom sorting usiing the third arugument

Comment: Could this be an XY problem? There may be a better data structure or algorithm to tackle the larger problem you have, rather than attempting (what I'll call) an Uno sort.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I was learning about the custom sort function and thought of this kind of scenario (Uno sort)

Comment: All comments are completely true. The real problem can of course not be solved with a sort function, because we are talking about cyclic permutations here. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, where the real problem is coming from.

But the background is the [Cyclic Permutation Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).

In your special case you are looking for a `k-cycle` where k is equal to the count of tuples. I drafted a solution for you that will show *all* cycles (not only the desired k-cycle).

And I use the notation described int the provided link. The other values of the tuple are  irrelevant for the problem.

But how to implement?

The secret is to select the correct container types. I use 2. For a cyle, I use a `std::unordered_set`. This can contain only unique elements. With that, an infinite cycle will be prevented. For example: 0,1,3,0,1,3,0,1,3 . . .  is not possible, because each digit can only be once in the container. That will stop our way through the permutations. As soon as we see a number that is already in a cycle, we stop.

All found cycles will be stored in the second container type: A `std::set`. The `std::set` can also contain only unique values and, the values are ordered. Because we store complex data in the `std::set`, we create a custom comparator for it. We need to take care that the `std::set` will not contain 2 double entries. And double would be in our case also 0,1,3 and 1,3,0. In our custom comparator, we will first copy the 2 sets into a `std::vector` and sort the `std::vector`s. This will make 1,3,0 to 0,1,3. Then we can easily detect doubles.

Please note:

I do always only store a value from the first permutation in the cycle. The 2nd is used as helper, to find the index of the next value to evaluate.

Please see the below code. I will produces 4 non trivial cycles- And one has the number of elements as expected: 1,3,5,2,4.

Porgram output:

```
Found Cycles:

(1,3,5,2,4)(3,5,2,4)(2,4)(5,2,4)
```

Please digest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

// Make reading easier and define some alies names
using MyType = int;
using Cycle = std::unordered_set<MyType>;
using Permutation = std::vector<MyType>;
using Permutations = std::vector<Permutation>;

// We do not want to have double results. 
// A double cyle is also a Cycle with elements in different order
// So define custom comparator functor for our resulting set
struct Comparator {
    bool operator () (const Cycle& lhs, const Cycle& rhs) const {
        // Convert the unordered_sets to vectors
        std::vector<MyType> v1(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
        std::vector<MyType> v2(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
        // Sort them 
        std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
        // Compare them
        return v1 < v2;
    }
};
// Resulting cycles
using Cycles = std::set<Cycle, Comparator>;

int main() {

    // The source data
    Permutations perms2 = {
        {3,4,1,2,5},
        {5,6,3,4,2} };

    // Lamda to find the index of a given number in the first permutation
    auto findPos = [&perms2](const MyType& m) {return std::distance(perms2[0].begin(), std::find(perms2[0].begin(), perms2[0].end(), m)); };

    // Here we will store our resulting set of cycles
    Cycles resultingCycles{};

    // Go through all single elements of the first permutation
    for (size_t currentColumn = 0U; currentColumn < perms2[0].size(); ++currentColumn) {

        // This is a temporary for a cycle that we found in this loop
        Cycle trialCycle{};

        // First value to start with
        size_t startColumn = currentColumn;

        // Follow the complete path through the 2 permutations
        for (bool insertResult{ true }; insertResult; ) {

            // Insert found element from the first permutation in the current cycle
            const auto& [newElement, insertOk] = trialCycle.insert(perms2[0][startColumn]);
            // Find the index of the element under the first value (from the 2nd permutation)
            startColumn = findPos(perms2[1][startColumn]);
            // Check if we should continue (Could we inster a further element in our current cycle)
            insertResult = insertOk && startColumn < perms2[0].size();
        }

        // We will only consider cycles with a length > 1
        if (trialCycle.size() > 1) {
            // Store the current temporary cycle as an additional result.
            resultingCycles.insert(trialCycle);
        }
    }


    // Simple output
    std::cout << "\n\nFound Cycles:\n\n";
    // Go through all found cycles
    for (const Cycle& c : resultingCycles) {
        // Print an opening brace
        std::cout << "(";
        // Handle the comma delimiter
        std::string delimiter{};

        // Print all integer values of the cycle
        for (const MyType& m : c) {
            std::cout << delimiter << m;
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        std::cout << ")";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this can't be achieved by using std::sort with a custom comparison function. Your comparison function doesn't establish a strict weak order onto your elements.

The std::sort documentation states that the comparison function has to fulfill the Compare requirements. The Comparison requirements say the function has to introduce a strict weak ordering.

- See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering for the properties of a strict weak order
- Compare requirements: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare

The comparison function has to return true if the first argument is before the second argument with respect to the strict weak order.

For example the tuple a=(4, 4, x) violates the irreflexivity property comp(a, a) == false

Or a=(4, 6, x) and b=(6, 4, y) violate the asymmetry property that if comp(a, b) == true it is not the case that comp(b, a) == true